# Label Encoder is not creating dummy variables

Tags: python, deep-learning, spyder

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

dataset=pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X=dataset.iloc[:, 3:13]
Y=dataset.iloc[:, 13]

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_en1=LabelEncoder()
X.values[:, 1]=label_en1.fit_transform(X.values[:, 1])
label_en2=LabelEncoder()
X.values[:, 2]=label_en2.fit_transform(X.values[:, 2])
```

I tried creating dummy variables but it is not happening. I am using X.values int the encoding section because the version of Spyder that I have does not support object arrays so let X and Y be dataframes. I added .values because it dataframes do not support slice terminology. Where might I have gone wrong ?
I created a similar program before for creating dummy variables and it worked then. I don't understand why it is not happening for this one.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or just the wrong output? Can you trim your code down and provide a [mcve] with sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

Can you pass in a slice of your slice? Like so:

`X.iloc[:, 1] = label_en1.fit_transform(X.iloc[:, 1])`

You would essentially trim your dataframe down to what appears to be an array

---

Instead of accessing `X.values`, try accessing the feature / column name directly:

`X['col_name'] = label_en1.fit_transform(X['col_name'])`

Comment: If I do that,I get an unhashable type slice error, because X and Y are dataframes. If convert X and Y into arrays then it I cannot access X because the version of Spyder that i have does not support object arrays